# Compilation error with MMA8451 accelerometer and attiny85 using ATTinyCore

Tags: compilation-errors, attiny85, wire-library

I am trying to use the Adafruit MMA8451 accelerometer with an attiny85. The Adafruit library uses Wire which doesn't work on the attiny so I used the ATTinyCore board files which have been modified to use a working version of Wire (github link: https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore).
I'm just trying to get the MMA8451 example to compile but here is the following error output:

```
C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp: In static member function 'static void SPIClass::begin()':

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:259:5: error: 'USI_SCK_PORT' was not declared in this scope

     USI_SCK_PORT |= _BV(USCK_DD_PIN);   //set the USCK pin as output

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:259:5: note: suggested alternative: 'USI_CLOCK_PORT'

     USI_SCK_PORT |= _BV(USCK_DD_PIN);   //set the USCK pin as output

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~

     USI_CLOCK_PORT

In file included from c:\users\sglaw\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.h:27,

                 from C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:20:

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:259:25: error: 'USCK_DD_PIN' was not declared in this scope

     USI_SCK_PORT |= _BV(USCK_DD_PIN);   //set the USCK pin as output

                         ^

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:259:25: note: suggested alternative: 'USI_PIN'

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:260:5: error: 'USI_DDR_PORT' was not declared in this scope

     USI_DDR_PORT |= _BV(DO_DD_PIN);     //set the DO pin as output

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:260:5: note: suggested alternative: 'USI_PORT'

     USI_DDR_PORT |= _BV(DO_DD_PIN);     //set the DO pin as output

     ^~~~~~~~~~~~

     USI_PORT

In file included from c:\users\sglaw\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\7.3.0-atmel3.6.1-arduino7\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                 from C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.h:27,

                 from C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:20:

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:260:25: error: 'DO_DD_PIN' was not declared in this scope

     USI_DDR_PORT |= _BV(DO_DD_PIN);     //set the DO pin as output

                         ^

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:260:25: note: suggested alternative: 'NOT_A_PIN'

C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI\SPI.cpp:261:26: error: 'DI_DD_PIN' was not declared in this scope

     USI_DDR_PORT &= ~_BV(DI_DD_PIN);    //set the DI pin as input

                          ^

Using library Wire at version 2.0.0 in folder: C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\Wire 
Using library Adafruit_MMA8451_Library at version 1.2.1 in folder: C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_MMA8451_Library 
Using library Adafruit_BusIO at version 1.14.1 in folder: C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_BusIO 
Using library Adafruit_Unified_Sensor at version 1.1.7 in folder: C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit_Unified_Sensor 
Using library SPI at version 2.0.0 in folder: C:\Users\sglaw\Documents\Arduino\hardware\ATTinyCore-2.0.0-dev\avr\libraries\SPI 
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATtiny85/45/25 (No Bootloader).
```

Any help much appreciated

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what this is, but I can't replicate your problem exactly.

Comment: I guess this is a problem with the 2.0.0 version of core. I installed version 1.5.2 through the boards manager and the example of the library compiles without errors

Comment: I'll try the 1.5.2 version

Comment: @chrisl Did you also not get their exact error?

Comment: @timemage In fact I got no error. Only the warning, that like 85% of memory is used globally. Compiled without problems. OP: Maybe you can report this at the cores github repository. They are asking for feedback on the 2.0.0 version.

Comment: @chrisl no errors with 1.5.2 (apart from same global variables warning), thanks for the help! I'll try report it on the github for 2.0.0